# MSBuildWorkspace : solution contains no documents and no projects on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn, code-analysis

I want to create an analyzer using roslyn, but first i need to get all the documents(.cs files) from the target solution.

i used the following code from Josh Varty's tutorial

```
        string solutionPath = @"C:\Users\hamza\Desktop\TestSolution\TestSolution.sln";
        var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

        var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;
        foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(project);
            foreach (var document in project.Documents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(project.Name + "\t\t\t" + document.Name);
            }
        }
```

But the result is null, i don't get any documents or projects.

the MSBuildWorkspace version is **3.0.0** i tried also **2.10.0** but the result is the same.

anyone have an idea about this ? or how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research I found this helpful issue post on Github:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/24767

this code worked fine

```
 var projectPath = @"C:\Users\hamza\Desktop\TestSolution\TestSolution.sln";
        using (var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create())
        {
            var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(projectPath).Result;

            foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
            {
                foreach (var document in project.Documents)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(project.Name + "\t\t\t" + document.Name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Finally to make things works fine i added this package:

Install-Package Buildalyzer.Workspaces -Version 2.2.0